# Access Violation On Create array of TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I am creating a multithreaded application, it creates a dynamic array of a class TThread, but the mystery for me, is that it causes an error 'Access Violation' to 'Create'

Code Form:

```
Unit UNT_Main;

Interface

Uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, UNT_Socks;

Type
  TFRM_Main = Class(TForm)
    Procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  Private
    Procedure OnUpload(Success: Boolean; SockAction: TSockAction);
  Public
    { Public declarations }
  End;

Var
  FRM_Main: TFRM_Main;
  Socks: Array Of TSocks;
  SA: Array Of TSockAction;

Implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Procedure TFRM_Main.OnUpload(Success: Boolean; SockAction: TSockAction);
Begin
  ShowMessage(SockAction.Response);
End;

Procedure TFRM_Main.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin

  SetLength(Socks, 5);
  SetLength(SA, 5);

  For I := 0 To High(Socks)-1 Do
  Begin
    SA[I].SUrl := 'http://google.com.co';
    Socks[I].Create(SA[I]);
    Socks[I].OnUpload := Self.OnUpload;
    Socks[I].Start;
  End;

End;

End.
```

Code UNT_Socks:

```
Unit UNT_Socks;

Interface

Uses Classes, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

// action script
Type
  TSockAction = Record
    SUrl: String;
    Response: String;
  End;

  // Eventos
Type
  // on upload event
  TUpload = Procedure(Success: Boolean; SockAction: TSockAction) Of Object;

  // Clase Socks, ejecuta las acciones
Type
  TSocks = Class(TThread)
    // Http indy sock
    Http: TIdHTTP;
    // action script
    FAtnSck: TSockAction;
    // Temp boolean response
    FbTempRet: Boolean;
  Private
    { Eventos }
    FOnUpload: TUpload;
    { Destructor }
    { Metodos & Funciones }
    Function UploadFile: Boolean;
    { Eventos }
    Procedure DoUpload;
  Protected
    Procedure Execute; Override;
  Public
    { Constructor }
    Constructor Create(SockAction: TSockAction);
    { Eventos }
    Property OnUpload: TUpload Read FOnUpload Write FOnUpload;
  End;

Implementation

{ Constructor }
Constructor TSocks.Create(SockAction: TSockAction);
Begin
  Inherited Create(True);

  FAtnSck := SockAction; // <===== Access Violation Here!
  Http := TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
End;

{ Eventos }
Procedure TSocks.DoUpload;
Begin
  // check if the event is assign
  If Assigned(FOnUpload) Then
    // call it
    FOnUpload(FbTempRet, FAtnSck);
End;

{ Execute }
Procedure TSocks.Execute;
Begin

  FbTempRet := UploadFile;
  Synchronize(DoUpload);

End;

Function TSocks.UploadFile: Boolean;
Var
  SRes: String;
Begin

  Try
    With Http Do
      FAtnSck.Response := Get(FAtnSck.SUrl);
  Except
    Result := False;
  End;

  Result := True;
End;

End.
```

What could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll follow her advice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your creation loop has 2 bugs in it:

1) You are looping to `High(Socks)-1` when you should be looping to `High(Socks)` instead. You are allocating arrays of 5 elements but only initializing 4 of them.  Don't use -1 with `High()`, use it with `Length()` instead.

2) You are misusing `TSocks.Create()`, which is why you are getting an AV.  You are calling it like an instance method instead of a constructor, but no instance has been constructed yet, thus the crash.

Use this instead:

```
For I := 0 To High(Socks) Do
Begin
  SA[I].SUrl := 'http://google.com.co';
  Socks[I] := TSocks.Create(SA[I]); // <-- here
  Socks[I].OnUpload := Self.OnUpload;
  Socks[I].Start;
End;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Socks[I].Create(SA[I]);
```

you should use

```
Socks[I]:= TSocks.Create(SA[I]);
```

Some minor notices:

why High(Socks)**-1** ?

will the result of Uploadfile always True?

is it necessary to free Http?

Comment: Yes, you need to free the `TIdHTTP` object when the thread is done using it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Remy.also TSocks in UNT_Socks has memory leak.Http(TIdHttp),FAtnSck(TSockAction)   field is not free after thread termination.

set FreeOnTermiate in consturctor of TSock

```
Constructor TSocks.Create(SockAction: TSockAction);
Begin
  Inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate:=True;
  FAtnSck := SockAction;  
  Http := TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
End;
```

then overriding destructor of TSock

```
 Destructor TSocks.Destroy;
 Begin

   SockAction.Free; // <===== if needed
   Http.Free;
   Inherited;
 End;
```

Comment: DO NOT use `FreeOnTerminate`.  Explicitally destroy the thread objects when you are done using them instead, such as during app shutdown.